Can anyone explain this bizarre GPU spiking I am seeing on a specific MacBook Pro?
I have 3 MacBooks, two are M1 Pro's and the third is an M3 Air - they all run normally with normal thermals and overall performance.
This issue persisted across many versions of macOS, I'm not sure when it started, but it's present on:

14.5
14.6
14.6.1
14.7

I have noticed that WindowServer on one of the M1 Pros spikes every 10-15s to ~35% GPU for a moment (2/3s), then goes back to 1%.
This behaviour is only seen on the one MacBook - the others seem to idle on 1-5% GPU usage for WindowServer.
I have tried a few things to try to identify the issue, including creating a fresh user account, and booting in safe mode (which essentially nukes all customisation AFAIK, certainly no apps ran on start-up) - but still the issue persists.
Nothing obvious in quick search of logs.
App energy impacts look normal.
I know it might seem trivial, but I wonder if it's a hardware issue?
Anything else I can try - I was going to install a fresh copy of macOS on a new APFS volume, but I think safe mode is essentially the same test?
Process sample here on PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/raw/Vx3zUwXm

Sample the process while it's showing the problem (and also while it's not, for comparison). There are command-line tools for this, or you can do it from Activity Monitor. Sometimes the symbols in the backtrace will give clues as to what's going on.

Added a sample, nothing unusual that I can see, unforch.
